# Saving, organizing and querying products, options/tags and categories

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, nosql

First of all, let me make clear that I'm not asking for any code; I just wan't some general ideas/guidance/opinions about how could I implement what I'm about to ask.

I'm starting to build an online e-commerce system (Yii2 + MongoDB, so, PHP + NoSQL), and there are two requisites that I'm not entirely sure how to implement without creating a huge mess in both my code and the database.

Both requisites are related, so I'll explain them both as one.

As any other serious e-commerce, it would have categories. And also, as any other serious e-commerce, each product will have `tags` or `options`. Let me explain a little bit further what I call `tags`/`options`.

Those are the available options that a user could select when buying a product, for example, the color or the size, the material, etc.

1. **Categories**

There would be multiple `general` categories as well as other sub-categories. For example, `Electronics` could be a general category and sub-categories would be `Computers` and `Smart TVs`. Then, `Motherboards` and `RAM` could be sub-categories of `Computers`.

This by itself could be easily stored in a database, but here it goes the problem:

- Each product should appear when listing any of the categories it belongs to, or the upper categories. That means that if I (as the final user) browse all the items in `Computers` category, I should see `NVIDIA GTX670` which belongs to the subcategory `Graphic cards` of the category `Computers`.

I could save each product the following way:

```
{
    _id: asdasfwetrw34tw34t245y45y,
    name: "NVIDIA GTX670",
    price: 99.50,
    ...
    ...
    categories: [
        "Electronics", //<-- just the ID of that group
        "Computers", //<-- just the ID of that group
        "Graphic cards" //<-- just the ID of that group
    ]
}
```

But:

- I'm not sure how fast would be a query for retrieving all the items of a certain category (and, of course, the items of all sub-categories).
- I'm not sure what other cons would that method have, so, please feel free to recommend any alternative schema for storing this.

2. **Tags/options**

This is where the real headache is.

Each option could belong to 0 or more categories and subcategories, so the category `Woman fashion` could have the options `size` and `color`, but the category  `Sunglasses` (subcategory of `Woman fashion`) could have only `color`, or even another set of options, completely different from `Woman fashion`.

Furthermore, the values inside each option (`red`, `green`, `blue` in the `color` option) could appear in random categories. So `Woman fashion` would have colors like `Strawberry Red` and `Tangerine`, while `Cars` would have `Carbon` and `Black metallic`.

Also, there would be several types of options:

- Completely static (like `size`, which could be only `S` or `M`, but never both. In any case, the administrator won't be able to write a *custom* size, like `Kind of small`; he would be able to just select what it's already in the database).
- Static that can combine together (like `colors`, which could be `red` or `green`, or a combination of colors that the admin chooses).
- Free-input (like `dimensions` or `weight`, that would, ideally, be input fields and dropdown values to join with. For example `[10]` | `(mg||kg|tons)` or `[20]` `(cm|m|km|miles)`).

I could save each option like this:

```
{
    option: "Color",
    type: "Static with combinations"
    values: [
        {
            value: "Red",
            categories: [
                "Sunglasses"
            ]
        },
        {
            value: "Green",
            categories: [
                "Sunglasses",
                "T-Shirts"
            ]
        },
        {
            value: "Black metallic",
            categories: [
                "Cars"
            ]
        }
    ],
    categories: [
        "Woman fashion", //<-- only the ID of this group
        "Cars" //<-- only the ID of this group
    ]
}
```

But I'm worried about how big a single option could turn to be, when there are 30 categories and each value of the option is set to appear in random categories.
Also I just don't see it clean enough, but maybe that is just me.

Anyways, as with the previous point, please feel free to suggest anything to can come up with, I'll greatly appreciate any feedback that you can give me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm running a e-commerce website, too. Here's my advice on how I implement the features you mentioned. Hope it helps.

- Categories

I organize them in a flat structure, in your case it would be:

```
    {_id: 1, name: "Electronics", parentId: 0, idPath: "/0/1/" ...}
    {_id: 2, name: "Computers", parentId: 1, idPath: "/0/1/2/", ...}
    {_id: 3, name: "Graphic Cards", parentId: 2, idPath: "/0/1/2/3/", ...}
```

And the product now needs to be only in the leaf categories. In your case:

```
    {
        _id: asdasfwetrw34tw34t245y45y,
        name: "NVIDIA GTX670",
        price: 99.50,
        ...
        ...
        categoryIds: [3]
    }
```

The product can be in multiple categories of course, so the `categoryIds` remains an array.
Here's the tricky part. When you list the `Electronics` category, you can find all its subcategories by:

```
    db.categories.find({idPath: /^\/0\/1/})
```

`idPath` index works here so it's going to be fast. when you find out all the sub-categories, you can easily find all the products in them (build index on the `categoryIds` of `Product` collection).

Or alternatively, you can read all the categories into memory and build a hash table with the key->categoryId, value->[all the subcategories]. Your categories usually won't change frequently and you won't have a lot of categories. Thus it's going to be fine.

- Tags/Options

First of all I think there's something wrong with your category. `Women fashion` is something generic, you should put your product into something more specific, and the options should be there too. For example, there maybe a category `coat` which has the `size` & `color`, other than `women fashion`. While there may still be `color` option in `women fashion` because it's a common characteristic of all subcategories.
If you think about it, why all the subcategories are organized in one parent category? because they have something in common. That common part should be the common options of the parent category. that is to say, there should be a inheritance between all the parent category and subcategories. For example:

> women fashion: color
>   |-coat: size
>   |-sun glasses: shape

Then `coat` would finally has 2 options `color` & `size`. `sun glasses`: `color` & `shape`. When you are viewing `women fashion`, there's only 1 option `color`. It filters the subcategories too because they inherit from `women fashion`.
As to the values of color, my idea is only use the standard colors `Strawberry Red` is actually `red`, `Tangerine` is actually `orange`. You don't really want them to appear when you filter the products. Otherwise there would be too many options, definitely not good for user experience.
However, besides `color` option from the category, my site also has something called `customizable options`. These options are only defined on the products. They never appear when you viewing category. Here you can have `Strawberry Red` & `Tangerine`. In my opinion, these are not 'natural' properties of a product. They are only used to make the user feel more comfortable when viewing the product. Thus also you can have option of this kind like `Tangerine with figure` etc.
One more thing about options. you may want to mark which options are supposed to be used for filtering products. For example `color` is definitely one. While `dimension` may be not.

About types of options. Yours are fine if it's enough for you. I have a lot more types like `Number`, `String`, `Single Choice`, `Multiple Choices`. I also plan to implement the `Unit`. Tricky part of `Unit` is that for example

```
1GB = 1024MB = 1024*1024B
```

So when you get a hard disk of 1GB and 1TB, you may want to do a conversion before filtering products. This is off the topic I'll get back to your question.

Note that although the options of different categories have the same name. They are not likely the same thing. `Material` of `Coat` and `Furniture` are 2 different things. So I tend to define different options for different categories. Thus there maybe `color` for `toys`, and `color` for `women fashion`. This does not conflict with the inheritance mentioned above because from some level, the subcategories begin to share the same options. This is completely related to how you organize your category structure. And if you want to change category structure or move products some time, it would be painful. So be careful when you define your categories.

That's all that comes up in my mind. I'm afraid I'm not native English speaker thus you may find some part of my answer hard to understand. Feel free to let me know.

Comment: That is a huge answer! It's 3am here, so give me a few hours so I can get some sleep and then I'll read it and reply ;)

Comment: Sure, take your time :)

Comment: I'm loving the category part! I never thought about it that way. About the tags `inheritance`, I'm not really sure it will work in my case. The client is a person that can change his mind 84 times per minute.Also, I'm afraid I will have colors that I don't want to appear in some categories, but I do want them in others (Cars vs Clothes). The units conversion is a good point, I'll keep that in mind! Thank you for the lengthy answer! kudos ;)

Comment: I agree, the `inheritance` part is not that practical. we implemented it in our website and it has it's limitations. especially when you want to change categories and move products among them. however, if the customer changes his mind frequently, I'm afraid it will always be a problem no matter which way you chose.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough. The purpose of `inheritance` is to enable product filtering from a certain level of categories. if `women fashion` has `color`, you can do filtering when viewing `women fashion`. While in `sun glasses`, you can filter products by both `color` and `shape`. Without inheritance, the filtering can only be done in the leaf category. That doesn't mean the `color` MUST appear in `women fashion`. It appears in a level where it makes sense. Maybe `Sun glasses` has subcategories `for kids`, `for adult`. Then you can place the `color` in the `Sun glasses` level.

Comment: Indeed, I think I understood what you mean. Anyways, I thought it would be possible to save the actual name of the tag (for example, `color`) and it's value (for example, `red`), and use MongoDB to search for all products that have a tag `color` and a value `red`. That way I won't need the inheritance, which does sounds good, but I'm afraid of my client changing too much things and me not being able to keep up with the changes.

Comment: Sounds good. Only problem I can think about is you need to enumerate all the products to get all the available options like `color`, `shape`, etc. And all the values of them too, for the user to be able to filter products.

Comment: @yaoxing: Thank you OP for the great question and thank you Yao for the in-depth explanation! Very helpful. I'm new to mongoDB and have had yet to work with categories. I was very confused at first as to how this is supposed to work, and this post helped clarify things. I wish the mongoDB docs gave some plain language examples of associating a category with a document. I think I've got a clearer image now thanks to your post. Going to re-structure my categories now and continue messing around. Genuinely appreciated and very helpful!

Comment: @natureminded Glad it helped. Let me know if you had further questions.

Comment: @yaoxing idPath is working if given a regex directly, but not if we build some pattern using a variable value. How to pass idPath using variable?